# What happens if maxIdle is greater than maxTotal in Apache Commons Pool 2?

Tags: pool

Is there anyone who has checked this kind of situation, where maxIdle is greater than maxTotal in Apache Commons Pool 2. What will happen then, which one applies as the maximum borderline?

ps: If possible with source code proof from apache commons pool

Answer (score 0):

Though Commons pool 2 configuration can be setup with maxIdle > maxTotal, but that configuration does not make sense because the pool ensures that the objects created would not exceed maxTotal.
Example, GenericOjbectPool.create ensures that the request to create an object does not exceed the maxTotal.
Where is maxIdle used ? Pool uses this during the Eviction cycle or when the object is returned back to the pool. For example,

1. when the object is returned, it would look at the maxIdle and take a decision of whether to destroy the object or return it to the pool.
2. when the eviction cycle runs, the objects idle are compared to the number of maxIdle to ensure excess objects are destroyed.

Therefore in reality maxIdle will never exceed the maxTotal.